# Using symmetry of the dot product, how can I prove this?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, projection, principal-component-analysis

Context of this question is projection perspective of principal component analysis, suppose we have orthonormal basis vectors $b_1, ... , b_m$ of the principal subspace where we project a data point $x_n \in \mathbb{R}^D$ onto subspace $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^D$ and $\text{dim}(U) = M$, and the projection of $x_n$ onto $U$ is denoted by $\widetilde{x}_n$ such that the euclideann distance between the two points is the minimum.

If we can represent $\tilde{x}_n$ as linear combination of $B = [b_1, ..., b_m]$ as: $$\tilde{x}_n = \sum_{m=1}^M z_{mn}b_m$$
Suppose that we know that $z_{in} = {x_{n}}^\intercal b_i = {b_i}^\intercal x_n$, so now we can write:
$$\tilde{x}_n = \sum_{m=1}^M z_{mn}b_m = \sum_{m=1}^M ({x_{n}}^\intercal b_m)b_m $$

My book says that exploiting the symmetry of the dot product we can write:
$$\tilde{x}_n = (\sum_{m=1}^M b_m {b_m}^\intercal)x_n$$

But I don't understand how? how can we take $x_n$ outside of the summation like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$
\sum_{m=1}^M (x_n^\top b_m)b_m
= \sum_{m=1}^M b_m(b_m^\top x_n)
= \sum_{m=1}^M (b_mb_m^\top) x_n
= \left(\sum_{m=1}^M b_mb_m^\top\right) x_n.
$$